# Transferring data from JavaScript in the head to html in the body

Tags: javascript, html, function, head

I'm having a problem here trying to transfer some information from the head of my html file, which is in JavaScript, to a table I want to create in a div in the body. I want to know if it's possible to pass information from the head to the body. Say, to create a table and have the input data be some declared variables in the head.

I have a function also and I would like to transfer output from that function and input it into the table. Here is some code that I have.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">


        theta = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
        r1 = Math.random() * R;
        r2 = R + (Math.random() * 100);
        ray = r1 + (Math.random() * (r2 - r1));
        point = [ray*Math.cos(theta), ray*Math.sin(theta)];


        var distance = funciton(x1, y1, R, x2, y2) {
            return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2) + Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2))) - R;
        };

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>



    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled "function".  Try this:

```
var distance = function() {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can assign the return value of that function to an input inside a table. Say you have the following input (I didn't see one in your markup, this is all example):

```
<input type="text" id="tableInput"/>
```

You can then set the value of this input:

```
document.getElementById("tableInput").value = distance();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what i needed. Already got the code finished up because of this. Honestly, I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function loadInTable()
{
var checkData=[
[1,1,2,3],
[4,5,6,7],
[8,9,10,11],
[12,13,14,15],
];
for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
{
for(var j=0;j<4;j++){
id=i+""+j;
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML =checkData[j][i];
}
}
}
```

```css
table,tr,td{
border:1px solid black;
}
table{
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="loadInTable()">
<center><table >
<tr><td id="00"></td><td id="10"></td><td id="20"></td><td id="30"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="01"></td><td id="11"></td><td id="21"></td><td id="31"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="02"></td><td id="12"></td><td id="22"></td><td id="32"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="03"></td><td id="13"></td><td id="23"></td><td id="33"></td></tr>
</table></center>
</body>
```